# Double pointer in the function

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to insert strings in the binary search tree.

So what I am to trying is,

parsing strings from a file(contains instruction set) and then inserting in the function

insertOpcodeFromFile().

So this function will execute

(*node) = Node_insert(&node,instruction).

the node will be the root of binary tree which is located in main function.

So in simple way to explain, I want to manipulate(insert) the root pointer in the main function by using double pointer in the other function contain insert function.

I have a simple understanding about the pointer, but in this situation, I need to use more than double pointer I think.

please explain me about the double pointer clearly using this example.

Here is my code(I commenting out insert_node)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef BINARYTREE_H_
#define BINARYTREE_H_

typedef struct node *NodePtr;

typedef struct node {
  char   *word;
  int     count;
  NodePtr left;
  NodePtr right;
    } Node;

NodePtr Node_alloc();
NodePtr Node_insert(NodePtr node_ptr, char *word);
void clearArray(char a[]);
void insertOpcodeFromFile(FILE *opcodeFile, NodePtr *node);

void    Node_display(NodePtr);
char   *char_copy(char *word);

#endif



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

FILE * opFile;
FILE * progFile;
struct node *root = NULL;


if ( argc != 4) {               // # of flag check
    fprintf(stderr, " # of arguments must be 4.\n" );
    exit(1);
}

opFile = fopen ( argv[1], "r");
if(opFile == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"There is no name of the opcode file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
progFile = fopen ( argv[2], "r");
if(progFile == NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr,"There is no name of the program file \n");
            exit(1);
    }

insertOpcodeFromFile(opFile, &root);
//Node_display(root);

}/* main is over */

void insertOpcodeFromFile(FILE *opcodeFile, NodePtr *node)
{
int fsize = 0;
int lengthOfInst = 0;
int c;
int i;
char buffer[100];
fsize = getFileSize(opcodeFile);
enum flag {ins,opc,form}; 
int flag = ins;
char instruction[6];
unsigned int opcode = 0;
unsigned char format;
 while (c != EOF)
{
    c = fgetc(opcodeFile);
    buffer[i++] = c;

    if (c == 32){
        switch (flag) {

        case ins:
            flag = opc;

            memcpy(instruction,buffer,i);
            instruction[i] = '\0';
            clearArray(buffer);
            i = 0;
           // printf("인스트럭션 : %s\n",instruction );
             break;

        case opc:
            flag = form;
            opcode = atoi(buffer);
            clearArray(buffer);
            i = 0;
           // printf("옵코드 : %d\n",opcode );
            break;

        default: 
             break;
        }/* end of switch */
    }/* end of if(space) */
    if((c == 10) || (c == EOF))
    {
        if (flag == form)
        {
            format = buffer[0];
            clearArray(buffer);
            i = 0;
           // printf("포멧: %c\n", format);

        }
        flag = ins;
       //node = Node_insert(node,instruction);


    }
}
//Node_display(node);
}
int getFileSize(FILE *opcodeFile)
{   int fsize = 0;
fseek(opcodeFile,0, SEEK_SET);
fseek(opcodeFile,0, SEEK_END);
fsize = (int)ftell(opcodeFile);
fseek(opcodeFile,0, SEEK_SET);
return fsize;
}
int countUntilSpace(FILE *opcodeFile, int currentPosition)
{   char readword[1];
char *space = " ";
char *nextLine = "/n";
int i = 0;
//printf("현재: %d\n",currentPosition );
while(1)
{   
    fread(readword, sizeof(char),1,opcodeFile);
    i++;

    if(strcmp(readword,space) == 0 || strcmp(readword,nextLine) == 0)
    {   
        //printf("break\n");
        break;
    }
}

fseek(opcodeFile,currentPosition ,SEEK_SET);
//printf("끝난 현재 :%d\n",ftell(opcodeFile) );
//printf("%I : %d\n",i );
return i - 1;
}
void clearArray(char a[])
{
memset(&a[0], 0, 100);
}

NodePtr Node_alloc()
{
return (NodePtr) malloc(sizeof(NodePtr));
}

NodePtr Node_insert(NodePtr node_ptr, char *word)
{
int cond;

if (node_ptr == NULL) {
    node_ptr = Node_alloc();
    node_ptr->word  = char_copy(word);
    node_ptr->count = 1;
    node_ptr->left  = node_ptr->right = NULL;
} else if ((cond = strcmp(word, node_ptr->word)) == 0) {
    node_ptr->count++;
} else if (cond < 0) {
    node_ptr->left = Node_insert(node_ptr->left, word);
} else {
    node_ptr->right = Node_insert(node_ptr->right, word);
}
return node_ptr;
}

void Node_display(NodePtr node_ptr)
{
if (node_ptr != NULL) {
    Node_display(node_ptr->left);
    printf("%04d: %s\n", node_ptr->count, node_ptr->word);
    Node_display(node_ptr->right);
}
}

char *char_copy(char *word)
{
char *char_ptr;

char_ptr = (char *) malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
if (char_ptr != NULL) {
    char_ptr = strdup(word);
}
return  char_ptr;
}
```

Comment: Your question and especially your code are very long. Please consider reducing it to something like 20 lines or people are unlikely to read it.  Try to single out the problem and remove anything that already works as expected.

Comment: In C, do not cast the result of a call to `malloc()`, `realloc()`, or `calloc()` - it is unnecessary and potentially masks the serious error of a missing prototype.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, in `main()`,

```
Node *root;
```

Why do you need to use a "double" pointer ( `Node **` ) in functions that alter `root` is because `root` value as to be set in these functions.

For instance, say you want to allocate a `Node` and set it into `root`.
If you do the following

```
void alloc_root(Node *root) {
   root = malloc(sizeof (Node));
   // root is a function parameter and has nothing to do 
   // with the 'main' root
}
...
   // then in main
   alloc_root( root );
   // here main's root is not set
```

Using a pointer to pointer (that you call "double pointer")

```
void alloc_root(Node **root) {
   *root = malloc(sizeof (Node)); // note the *
}
...
   // then in main
   allow_root( &root );
   // here main's root is set
```

The confusion comes probably from the `Node *root` in main, `root` being a pointer to a `Node`. How would you set an integer `int i;` in a function `f`? You would use `f(&i)` to call the function `f(int *p) { *p = 31415; }` to set `i` to the value `31415`.

Consider `root` to be a variable that contains an address to a `Node`, and to set its value in a function you have to pass `&root`. `root` being a `Node *`, that makes another `*`, like `func(Node **p)`.